# SWIFT 2.2 Warning: Attempt to present TabBar Controller on SignInViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: swift, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, viewdidload, viewdidappear

I have a SignInVC, a button to transition to a TabbarVC *not segue for the purpose of using a custom transitioning*. Although it runs fine, an error pops up  when i press the signIn button in the Debug Area.

In the SignInVC

```
     @IBAction func onTapButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    btnFromNib.animate(1, completion: { () -> () in

        let myTabbarController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabbarController") as! UITabBarController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = myTabbarController

        myTabbarController.transitioningDelegate = self

        self.presentViewController(myTabbarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })

}
```

What am i doing wrong? ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you presenting the tab bar controller if you are changing the root viewcontroller to it anyway?

Comment: After the user signs in, it will present the user with the TabbarVC.

Comment: But if you have changed the rootViewController to the tab bar wont it already be visible on the screen and doesn't need presenting?

Comment: Sorry, no it won't be. It won't even display the VC, rather a blank screen hence why i would need to present the VC. Try out the code in a Tabbar VC.

Comment: @MartinQ   self.presentViewController(myTabbarController, animated: true, completion: nil) remove this line...why do you need that....i guess you are brother of Martin R :)

Comment: @anishparajuli , thanks a great deal. Worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since,you are changing your `rootViewController` you dont need to present it..So remove this line

```
   self.presentViewController(myTabbarController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```